# OpenCV: in bag of visual words, how to pass descriptors instead of keypoints?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-computing

I'm implementing the [Bag of Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) model through OpenCV.

My workflow is the following:

1. Compute SIFT keypoints & descriptors for each image in the dataset
2. Using the descriptors and `cv::BOWKMeansTrainer`, compute the `k` centroids using `k`-means algorithm via `cv::BOWKMeansTrainer.cluster()`
3. Using `cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` compute the `word` of each image `img` from the dataset (same for a query) through `compute(img,keyPoints,word)` (we can use `keyPoints` that we computed during step 1.).

The problem is in point 3: I think that `compute` compute *again* the descriptors of `img`. This is terribly inefficient, we already computed the needed descriptors in step 1.!

How can I call `compute` passing the already computed descriptors?

**Notice** that I didn't check the implementation of compute, but I'm quite sure (from my understanding of the BoF model) that interally is going to compute the descriptors.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120374/re-using-descriptors-with-bowimgdescriptorextractor), without a solution.

Comment: As per the similar question linked (posted by myself), I'm fairly certain there's no obvious way around this unfortunately. The most straight forward solution would be to create your own implementation of BOWImgDescriptorExtractor from the existing source code, and simply modify it to take the descriptors, rather than re-compute them. I'd be interested to see if someone has another solution though.

Comment: This is unbelievable :D OpenCV it's the most used image-processing library and sometimes it's really elegant. How is it possible that they didn't think that? :D

Comment: I thought it seemed very unlikely myself when I discovered this, so I literally spent a day trying to find the solution within OpenCV, to no avail. When I noticed that they had added [the following method](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d6b/classcv_1_1BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.html#a2c3540b57b4f74b4e87778e3cb338bb0), that kind of confirmed my suspicions that it must have previously been missing from the library.